# undefined function ldap_connect()

Tags: php, apache, ldap

I have a problem with my extension ldap:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function: ldap_connect()

`Apache` and `PHP` are installed on a `Windows 2012 R2` virtual machine.

**The version of PHP is 7.0**

I have already edited the `php.ini` folder and enabled `php_ldap.dll`

I have already added the files `libsasl.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` in `System32`, `SysWOW64` and `Apache24/bin`.

I have already added `path of my PHP` to `Windows System Path`.

And obviously I have restarted my Apache and my virtual machine.

[This is an extract of my `phpinfo()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGxWt.jpg)

This is the only place which ldap appears in `phpinfo()`

Please could you resolve my problem?

PS: Excuse my English, I'm French.

> EDIT 02/06/2017: I have solved the problem. Apache can't load
> ldap.dll with the error "is not a valid Win32 application". I have
> changed the dll (downloaded a new php and take the ldap.dll). It works!

Comment: `libsasl.dll and ssleay32.dll` only need to be in your `Apache24/bin` If you put them everywhere you will get probelms later when you want to change the version of any of these

Comment: Most likely the extension fails to load, possibly due to binary incompatibility reasons. Please take a look at your http servers error log file. Usually you will find a hint on that.

Comment: Are you sure you edited the `php.ini` file that lives in the `apache\bin` folder? The one in the `php` folder is used only by PHP CLI

Comment: I have solved the problem.
Apache can't load ldap.dll with the error "is not a valid Win32 application".
I have change the dll (download a new php and take the ldap.dll).
It work !